# Unexpected E0F When Defining an SQL Query as a Variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was coding a small forum and I keep coming across `unexpected EOF` errors in my PHP code where I set an SQL query as a PHP variable. I expect the code to not have that error and to show the category name and description in the forum application that is stored in the MySQL database. I tried looking elsewhere on the internet and the MySQL and PHP manual to no avail.

According to my eyes, the syntax is correct up until I start typing `$_GET['id']` in `mysqli_real_escape_string($connected, $_GET['id'])` in line line 7 of `category.php` and anything with a `POST` method in `create_cat.php`. This is most likely not just my IDE because it shows up in my error log when the program is run. My code is shown below. This is a small part of the entire file, but just enough to hopefully reproduce the error.

*category.php*:

```
        //do a query for the topics
        $sql = "SELECT  
                    topic_id,
                    topic_subject,
                    topic_date,
                    topic_cat
                FROM
                    topics
                WHERE
                    topic_cat = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
```

There are more files in the forum application, but I'm guessing they won't be needed.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images.

Comment: Please post in the question itself.

Comment: Those errors are coming from your IDE, not PHP.

Comment: Usually "unexpected EOF" means you have unbalanced quotes or braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a function call inside a string won't work. You need to call the function outside the string and then concatenate it.

Also, you were missing the `'` after the function call.

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connected, $_GET['id']) . "'";
```

However, you really should learn to use prepared statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id = ?";
$stmt = $connected->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

If you prefer the procedural syntax for some reason:

```
$sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connected, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$stmt->bind_param`

Comment: for ```$connected``` in ```$stmt = $connected->prepare($sql);``` be changed to ```$stmt``` or not? I got an error either way. When it was ```$connected```, the error was that it was calling an undefined function, and when it was ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null```

Comment: `$connected` is the variable in your script that holds the `mysqli` connection. You have `mysqli_query($connected, $sql);`

Comment: The equivalent function version is `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`

Comment: All the `$stmt->XXX` methods are equivalent tp `mysqli_stmt_XXX` functions.

Comment: Not removed https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @NotAnerd The alias was removed, the function it's an alias for was not.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the functional versions. None of these functions have been removed.

Comment: It still errors out with ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param()```. Below is my code so far for the queries: ```$sql = "INSERT INTO categories (cat_name, cat_description) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $statement = $connected->prepare($sql);
    $stmt = $connected->bind_param("ss", $_POST['cat_name'], $_POST['cat_description']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->close();
    $result = mysqli_query($connected, $sql);

Comment: You didn't change `$connected->bind_param` to `$stmt->bind_param`.